# Asp.net core logging to file is not working on iis server inside inetpub\wwwroot\project folder

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-logging

I have turned on my file logging on asp.net core and works perfectly fine on development. But when I install it on IIS server then it does not produce any log files. I am storing my project into inetpub\wwwroot directory. My logger configuration in startup.cs is like this below:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddFile(Path.Combine("\\Logs\\storefront_retail_log_{Date}.txt"), LogLevel.Information);
}
```

If I change the above path to be any static path outside the inetpub then it will start logging. I can think the above as a permission issue. But I don't have user called IIS_IUSER in my system to allow permission.

Turning on stdoutLogEnabled produces file but not of Logger. I am using Serilog.Extensions.Logging.File to log to file.

I think it will be easier to put log file contained to the project itself. Any suggestion on where to put our log files or fix the permission issue?

Thank you

Comment: In my case all problem was Application-Pool-User access rights.  But no warning in event log.

Answer (score 1):

Is this well typed path **inetpu**\wwwroot in your explenation or just typo (**inetpub**)?
On Windows with IIS there should be IUSR try to set folders and files permissions granting read, write, modify access. That should do the "trick".

Here is more information on both accounts [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-for-security/understanding-built-in-user-and-group-accounts-in-iis)

I hope it helps. Let us know.

Comment: Oops, that was a typo. Yes, I tried using IUSR also but the result is the same. No log file is created.

Comment: Do you have access to the Event logs on the server? If so, perhaps you can get a hint on what is going on and if it's permission in Windows Logs > Application and Windows Logs > System.

Comment: Yes I have and there is no messages on event log saying cannot write to a file

Comment: I've never used Serilog extension. Is this extension working properly on your development machine? What would happen if you change directory on you dev. machine?

Comment: Yes, this is working properly on development. This is working properly on IIS server too if I give a path like C:\Logs\logname.txt. But won't work with relative path inside inetpub\wwwroot folder

Comment: Path.Combine(_HostEnv.WebRootPath, "\\Logs\\storefront_retail_log_{Date}.txt"); where private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _HostEnv; Try this one making it absolute application path. Let me know what would happen.